# Rails Date#strptime parsing dates incorrectly before year 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why does Rails' `Date#strptime` parse "13/08" as August 15 or August 14 before the year 200?

```
Date.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')  #=> Thu, 15 Aug 0099
Date.strptime('13/08/100', '%d/%m/%Y') #=> Fri, 14 Aug 0100
Date.strptime('13/08/199', '%d/%m/%Y') #=> Tue, 14 Aug 0199
Date.strptime('13/08/200', '%d/%m/%Y') #=> Wed, 13 Aug 0200
```

Comment: What is your Rails and Ruby version? Which OS ? What is your timezone?

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't happen in plain ruby.

`puts Date.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')`
`"0099-08-13"`

- Ruby: 2.3.1
- Rails: 4.2.7.1
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Timezone: Brisbane/Australia

Comment: What is so strange in this behavior? What do you expect? http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime specifies that %Y directive expects at least 4 digits.

Comment: Well, parsing dates from year 0 to year 99 is 2 days ahead, parsing dates from year 100 to year 199 is 1 day ahead, and parsing dates from year 200 onward is fine for '%Y'. I realise '%Y' isn't really supposed to be used this way, but it's pretty weird that it's not consistently incorrect.

Comment: @DaveAllie what does `Date.method(:strptime)` return?

Comment: Does it still happen when you use `%y` instead of `%Y`?

Comment: @EricDuminil `99` denotes the year 99, not 1999, so `%Y` is correct here.

Comment: The documentation does say that %Y is year with century, and should have at least 4 digits. I think it should be written '13/08/0099' just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @EricDuminil which documentation are you referring to? [`Time#strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) says: _"%Y – Year which may include century, if provided"_

Comment: My bad. I look at 2.1.1 documentation (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html), which said `Year with century`.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot duplicate the results in the question, with any system, ruby version, rails version or timezone. Which gems do you use?

Comment: @Stefan: `2.3.1 :002 > Date.method(:strptime)`
`Date#strptime(str, fmt)`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: `2.3.1 :001 > Date.strptime('13/08/0099', '%d/%m/%Y')`
`Thu, 15 Aug 0099`
`2.3.1 :002 > Date.strptime('13/08/1999', '%d/%m/%Y')`
`Fri, 13 Aug 1999`
`2.3.1 :003 > Date.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%y')`
`Fri, 13 Aug 1999`

Comment: Thanks. What about `Date.strptime('13/08/0099', '%d/%m/%Y').to_s`, `Date.strptime('13/08/0099', '%d/%m/%Y').inspect`, `Date.strptime('13/08/0099', '%d/%m/%Y').day` and `Date.strptime('13/08/0099', '%d/%m/%Y').method(:inspect)` ?

Comment: Using https://github.com/daveallie/where_is: `2.3.1 :001 > Where.is(Date, :strptime)`
`["/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/timecop-0.7.0/lib/timecop/time_extensions.rb", 46]` which leads to https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/blob/v0.7.0/lib/timecop/time_extensions.rb#L46. So it's not Date, that's buggy, it's Time??

Comment: `2.3.1 :004 > Time.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')`
`0099-08-13 00:00:00 +0000`
`2.3.1 :005 > Time.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y').to_date`
`Thu, 15 Aug 0099`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up :

If you don't use timecop gem, Date#strptime seems to work fine for year < 200.

If you use timecop, Date#strptime is overwritten and uses Time#to_date, which seems to return wrong values for year < 200.

Easy solutions, either :

- don't use timecop
- use Date#strptime_without_mock_date if you do use
  timecop
- use Date.new + Time#strptime

Harder solution :
understand what's wrong with the implementation of [Time#to_date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-to_date) (see Stefan's explanation.)

```
[0] pry(main)> Time.local(99,8,13).to_date
=> #<Date: 0099-08-15 ((1757444j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[1] pry(main)> Date.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')
=> #<Date: 0099-08-13 ((1757442j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[2] pry(main)> require 'timecop'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Date.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')
=> #<Date: 0099-08-15 ((1757444j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[4] pry(main)> Date.strptime_without_mock_date('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')
=> #<Date: 0099-08-13 ((1757442j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[5] pry(main)> time = Time.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')
=> 0099-08-13 00:00:00 +0053
[6] pry(main)> Date.new(time.year,time.month,time.day)
=> #<Date: 0099-08-13 ((1757442j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Using [github.com/daveallie/where_is](https://github.com/daveallie/where_is):
>
> ```
> Where.is(Date, :strptime)
> #=> ["/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/timecop-0.7.0/lib‌​/timecop/time_extens‌​ions.rb", 46]
> ```
>
> which leads to [timecop/time_extensions.rb#L46](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/blob/v0.7.0/lib/timecop/time_extensions.rb#L46):
>
> ```
> def strptime_with_mock_date(str, fmt)
>   Time.strptime(str, fmt).to_date
> end
> ```

That's correct, Timecop turns:

```
Date.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y')
#=> #<Date: 0099-08-13 ((1757442j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

into:

```
Time.strptime('13/08/99', '%d/%m/%Y').to_date
#=> #<Date: 0099-08-15 ((1757444j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

> So it's not `Date`, that's buggy, it's `Time`?

It's not exactly buggy, just different. `Time#to_date` interprets the values as proleptic Gregorian calendar dates:

```
Date.new(99, 8, 13, Date::GREGORIAN).new_start
#=> #<Date: 0099-08-15 ((1757444j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

versus:

```
Date.new(99, 8, 13, Date::ITALY).new_start
#=> #<Date: 0099-08-13 ((1757442j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Here's a summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar):

```
Julian range             | Proleptic Gregorian range | Gregorian ahead by:
-------------------------|---------------------------|--------------------
03/03/4    - 01/03/100   | 01/03/4    - 28/02/100    | −2 days
02/03/100  - 29/02/200   | 01/03/100  - 28/02/200    | −1 days
01/03/200  - 28/02/300   | 01/03/200  - 28/02/300    |  0 days
29/02/300  - 27/02/500   | 01/03/300  - 28/02/500    |  1 day
28/02/500  - 26/02/600   | 01/03/500  - 28/02/600    |  2 days
27/02/600  - 25/02/700   | 01/03/600  - 28/02/700    |  3 days
26/02/700  - 24/02/900   | 01/03/700  - 28/02/900    |  4 days
25/02/900  - 23/02/1000  | 01/03/900  - 28/02/1000   |  5 days
24/02/1000 - 22/02/1100  | 01/03/1000 - 28/02/1100   |  6 days
23/02/1100 - 21/02/1300  | 01/03/1100 - 28/02/1300   |  7 days
22/02/1300 - 20/02/1400  | 01/03/1300 - 28/02/1400   |  8 days
21/02/1400 - 19/02/1500  | 01/03/1400 - 28/02/1500   |  9 days
20/02/1500 - 04/10/1582  | 01/03/1500 - 14/10/1582   | 10 days
```